# How to send values from jQuery-AJAX function to PHP file and access those values in PHP file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've written a jQuery-AJAX function as follows :

```
$('#request_form').submit(function(e) {
  var form = $(this);
  var stud_id = $('#stud_id').val();
  var reg_date = $('#reg_date').val();
  var formdata = false;


  var fileInput = $("#receipt_image")[0];  

  /*I want to pass values of below variables to the PHP file.*/
  var ImgSizeInBytes = fileInput.files[0].size;
  var filename = $('input[type=file]').val().split('\\').pop();
  var customer_id = $('#customer_id').val();
 /*These values need to send to PHP file and access there */

  if(window.FormData) {
    formdata = new FormData(form[0]);
  }

  var formAction = form.attr('action');

  $.ajax({
    url         : 'student_request.php',
    type        : 'POST',    
    cache       : false,
    data        : formdata ? formdata : form.serialize(),
    contentType : false,
    processData : false,
    success: function(response) {
      var responseObject = $.parseJSON(response);    
      if(responseObject.error_message) { 
        if ($(".alert-dismissible")[0]) {
          $('.alert-dismissible').remove();   
        }  
        var htmlString = "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible' role='alert'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>"+responseObject.error_message+"</div>";    
        $(htmlString).insertBefore('div.modal-body #request_form');        
      } else { 
        alert("Student successfully registered...!!!");       
      }
    }
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Now I'm able to access the values filled in by user on a form by means of `$_POST` array in PHP file. But I also want to pass the values I put in comment in my code above to the PHP file.

The values/parameters which I want to send are not part of a form fields. I've manipulated the values of these variables. So they can't come in `$_POST` array.

My issue is how should I send these values to PHP file and how should I access these values in PHP file?

Answer (score 0):

You should change this: `formdata ? formdata : form.serialize()`

Store this in a variable and concatenate the values you want to send.

For Example:

```
var pars = formdata ? formdata : form.serialize();
pars += "&myField1=myValue1&myField2=myValue2"
```

Comment: This is not a complete solution. How should I access these data in PHP? Can you please integrate this in my code?

Comment: With $_POST["myField1"] you can access the value of the myField1 parameter (in this case, "myValue1").

Answer (score 0):

As @chris said, all you need to do is to concatenate your own hidden variables to post variables. As I see, you are confused about how to use those extra variables in your php file, here's simple example:

```
var params = formdata ? formdata : form.serialize();
params += "param1=myExtraVar1&param2=myExtraVar2";
```

So now you have all variables ready to be sent to your php file, modify your data parameter in ajax call like this:

```
...data: params,
```

So far, so good. Let's see the other side (PHP)

```
<?php 
    // get the variables you want to treat.
    $param1 = $_POST['param1']; // now you have access to this variable from ajax call
   // Notice you can display all variables you have in superglobal variable POST 
   // by dumping it using either var_dump($_POST) or print_r($_POST)
```

Hope this helps understand better the process, and feel free to comment and I'll get back to you

Another thing I captured and I'd like to share with you is that you can use datatype to JSON instead of casting your returned response, so you can put this code anywhere inside your ajax call:

```
dataType: "json", // if you put this in last line, omit the comma, otherwise leave as it is
```